# File won't open when being passed from a function

Tags: python-3.x, file-handling

How come it's not opening the file I put into the function? It opens when I plug the file name directly into the main program, but not when I try to pass it through the function. It gives me a `FileNotFoundError`.

```
def get_valid_filename(prompt):
  '''Use prompt (a string) to ask the user to type the name of a file. If
  the file does not exist, keep asking until they give a valid filename.
  Return the name of that file.'''

  filename = input(prompt)
  if os.path.isfile(filename) == False:
    print ("That file does not exist.")
    filename = input(prompt)

  return filename

if __name__ == '__main__':

  prompt = 'enter the name of the file with unknown author:'
  mystery_filename = get_valid_filename(prompt)

  # readlines gives us the file as a list of strings each ending in '\n'
  text = open(mystery_filename, 'r').read()

  print (text)
```

Comment: you probably meant: `while not isfile(path): path = input("path?")` Notice `while` instead of `if`. Better yet, just use `return open(path)` inside try/except (also in a loop) to return the file object directly.

Comment: I can't open the file inside the function. It has to stay in the main program.

Comment: please, fix the indentation, python is unreadable without the proper indentation.

Comment: Indentation has been fixed

Comment: Replace `if` with `while`. The problem is that although a bad input invokes another input, this second one is going to be passed through your function anyway even if it is also bad.

Answer (score 0):

`get_valid_filename` should look like this:

```
def get_valid_filename(prompt):
    while True:
        filename = input(prompt):
        if os.path.exists(filename):
            return filename
        print('that file does not exist')
```